# AngularJS file upload error with Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloudinary, ng-file-upload

I try to run the photo_album sample with angularjs using ng-file-upload
 https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/tree/master/samples/photo_album
 and I got this error error

`{"message":"Missing required parameter - file"}`

Comment: More information is needed to investigate the cause for this error.
Any code changes you made? What were the steps you took that led to this result? The payload of the HTTP request which was sent to Cloudinary. etc.